# A regular expression to replace different combinations of double quotes inside a double-quoted string

Tags: regex, pcre

**A regular expression to replace different combinations of double quotes inside a double-quoted string.**

Can't clear JSON with one regular expression (for PCRE). I just don't know what to do next.

```
("title":")[\s\S]+(", "partid":)
```

I've tried various search and replacement options. For example, **("title":"[^"]*)(")([^"]*)(")(, "p) $1$3$4$5**, then the same for two double quotes, for three, and so on.

Examples of strings:

```
{ "DT_RowId":"c2a839fb-580a-11e8-bac6-00155d080416", **"title":"Гайка 7/16"-14" UNC топорна;14H813;P88344 12""**, "partid":"S.4964", "manufacturerid":"2a7dc482-af13-11de-88d3-00e081b05e17", "manufacturer":"SPAREX", "quantity":">10", "price":"8.93", "actionprice":"", "rep":1, "img":0 } , { "DT_RowId":"05d8b40c-ec93-11dd-8f72-00e081b05e05", "title":"Нож ротора (зам.501060)", "partid":"501063", "manufacturerid":"3a7e891f-07ba-11de-8a95-00e081b05e17", "manufacturer":"Geringhoff", "quantity":">10", "price":"932.27", "actionprice":"584.90", "rep":1, "img":1 } , { "DT_RowId":"b7c6c9ee-adca-11e3-8202-00155d012119", **"title":"Олива моторна "CASTROL VECTON" 10W40 E4"/E7", 208L"**, "partid":"RB-V14E4E7-208L", "manufacturerid":"763d805e-c53b-11de-9210-00e081b05e05", "manufacturer":"CASTROL", "quantity":">10", "price":"111.60", "actionprice":"", "rep":1, "img":1 } , { "DT_RowId":"05d8b41d-ec93-11dd-8f72-00e081b05e05", **"title":"Н""о"ж"**, "partid":"501251", "manufacturerid":"3a7e891f-07ba-11de-8a95-00e081b05e17", "manufacturer":"Geringhoff", "quantity":">10", "price":"719.45", "actionprice":"", "rep":1, "img":1 }
```

Please help. Please help. How can I remove or escape double quotes between **"title":"** and **", "partid":**

Comment: Which programming language do you use?

Comment: @Jan I use the Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. But after I get what I want with PCRE, I will automate this process on Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|"title":").*?\K"(?=.*?"\s*,\s*"partid":)
```

Replace with an empty string. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nYhzp2/1).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|"title":")`  - end of the previous match or `"title":"` string
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars, other than linebreak chars, as few as possible
- `\K` - a match reset operator
- `"` - a `"` char
- `(?=.*?"\s*,\s*"partid":)` - followed with any 0+ chars, other than linebreak chars, as few as possible, `"`, 0+ whitespaces, `,`, 0+ whitespaces and `"partid":`.

Comment: @avemoto If you want to use it in Python, you can use it with PyPi `regex` library, install it using `pip install regex` in the console/terminal window.

Comment: @CarySwoveland [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nYhzp2/7). If it's important to optimize performance you would use something like this: ```\G(?:\A(*COMMIT).*?"title":")?.*?"(?:\s*,\s*"partid":(*COMMIT)(*F))?(?<=\K")```